# Calculate $\lim \inf$ and $\lim \sup$ of $A_n$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

$A_n = (-1+\frac1n,2-\frac1n), $ for odd n,

$A_n = [0,n]$ for even n.

Calculate lim inf $A_n$ and lim sup $A_n$

I am unsure of how to go about calculating these limits.
I know that $\liminf A_n = ⋃_m⋂_{(n≥m)}A_n$ but I am not sure how to apply this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\liminf_nA_n$ is the set of those real numbers which belong to $A_n$, for every large enough $n$. So, $\liminf_nA_n=[0,2)$. In fact:

- if $x<0$, then $x$ belongs to no $A_n$ for even $n$;
- if $x\geqslant 2$, then $x$ belongs to no $A_n$ with odd $n$;
- if $x\in[0,2)$, then $x\in A_n$, for each $n>1$.

On the other hand, the set $\limsup_nA_n$ is the set of those real numbers which belong to infinitely $A_n$'s. Therefore, it is equal to $(-1,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would you mind showing steps that can be taken to get to [0,2)? And also, for calculating $lim sup$, to help understand this further.

Comment: What do you think now?

Comment: Thanks so much, I understand where the answers are coming from now!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.